# Set the property of channel adapter

Tags: java, jpos

i have a channel configuration in my 10_channel_jpos.xml and i want to be able to get the ip and port from a property file and set it from my code, because those values could change

```
<channel-adaptor
      name="mybank-channel-adaptor-pri"
      class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">

   <channel name="ServerA-Channel" class="org.jpos.iso.channel.NACChannel" 
            logger="Q2" realm="ServerA-Channel" 
            packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87APackager"> 

        <property name="timeout" value="3600000"/>
        <property name="host" value="${myBankHostPrimary}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${myBankPortPrimary}"/>
        <property name="packager-config" value="cfg/base1.xml" />
        <property name="keep-alive" value="true" />
    </channel>

    <in>from-mybank-pri</in>
    <out>to-mybank-pri</out>
    <reconnect-delay>5000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor>
```

and a property file

```
###### GENERAL INFO
NODE = NODE001
######  Environment
env=DEV
######  Ports we listens to
server_listen_port = 9999
######  Target host information
myBankHostPrimary=127.0.0.1
myBankPortPrimary=8001
###### DEBUG STUFF
debugParticipant=true
```

and a main class

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChannelAdaptor channel= (ChannelAdaptor) NameRegistrar.get ("mybank-channel-adaptor-pri");

channel.setHost = "127.0.0.1"; // Value gotten from the property file
            System.out.println(channel.getHost());
    }
```

please how do i set the property host value and port value?

my folder structure is

```
bin
.....bsh
.....q2.bat
.....start.bat
.....stop


build
    ......META-INF
             .......org
                      .......jpos
                              ........config
                                       ......Q2-decorator.property
    .....cfg
          .....config.properties (my property file)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, you could add the `configuration-factory` attribute to your `<channel>` element and create your own ConfigurationFactory. Then your implementation can pick the properties values from wherever  you want.

You can find an example here: https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/modules/sysconfig/src/main/java/org/jpos/ee/SysConfigConfigurationFactory.java

The SysconfigConfigurationFactory picks properties from a database's `sysconfig` table. You can use it as an inspiration to create your own custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps:

- stop the channel
- set the channel and port
- start the channel

Inside your code you would do something like this:

```
channel.stop();
channel.setPort(port);
channel.setHost(host);
channel.start();
```

Comment: Andres Alcarraz thank you for your reply, but please do i implement the above code before or after i start Q2?

Comment: @Dexter As you are using NameRegistrar to access the channel adaptor, I assumed that you have already started Q2 previously in your main and were trying to dynamically change a running instance. Channel adaptor registers itself in the registry in the start phase of the deployment process. So Q2 has to be running to access qbeans from NameRegistrar. If you want to set the channel and port, prior to starting Q2 you should state that in your question and I'll come later with that answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the properties before launching Q2, you need to use a  [decorator](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/doc/src/asciidoc/module_freemarker_decorator.adoc). This is included in standard jpos now.

As  [that page states](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/doc/src/asciidoc/module_freemarker_decorator.adoc#activation-steps) you need to create a resource in your project residing at 'META-INF/org/jpos/config/Q2-decorator.properties' of your classpath (not the filesystem!).

The content:

```
config-decorator-class=org.jpos.q2.freemarker.FreemarkerDecorationProvider    (1)
config-files=cfg/config.properties                                            (2)
```

1. This property tells Q2 to use the FreemarkerDecoratorProvider as its decorator.
2. This property defines a comma separated list of files which will be used as configuration files.

where in cfg/properties would be your properties file.

You also have to add a dependency to org.jpos.ee:jposee-freemarker-decorator. I don't know if you are building with maven or gradle.

Comment: thank you once more Andres i appreciate, but please i have done the above suggestion, but i still get    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${mybankPortPrimary}"

Comment: Can you update your question with the version of jpos you are  using?

Comment: @Dexter Also can you share the code that's giving you that exception?

Comment: @Dexter, I updated the answer, you need to add the dependency to org.jpos.ee:jposee-freemarker-decorator:2+ in gradel, or the maven equivalent. Also you have a mismatch in the properties, mybankHostPrimary in xml and myBankHostPrimary in the properties file, the same goes for the port. Are you sure you added the 'META-INF/org/jpos/config/Q2-decorator.properties' file to the classpath and not only in the working directory? It is working fine for me.

Comment: i have updated the question to include the folder structure .The code that gives error, once i start q2, i get  error starting service
    <exception name="For input string: "${myBankPortPrimary}"">

Comment: @Dexter your meta-inf is in lowecase, and as the answer says it has te in uppper

Comment: i have updated it and run again...its still the same error....i am really getting frustrated and loosing hope already

Comment: How are you starting your program? You didn't answer about jpos version, but I don't think that's the issue, most probably build is not in your classpath. Please add that to the question.

Comment: @Dexter also you are missing config in your structure:  'META-INF/org/jpos/config/Q2-decorator.properties'

Comment: You still did not answer my question about how are you executing the program, answer this are you really sure that your build directory is part of the classpath? i'm sure  this approach works I tested it my self.All Ihad to do is follow the steps of the link I passed and your file seem to created following that very same example, you are doing something. So I guess someone did that and now you are trying to making work in your machine

Comment: i am executing it by calling java -jar jposee.jar to start q2

Comment: Then the build directory is not in your classpath, it's a Java thing, you need to understand how java works to use a java library/framework

Comment: Then the build directory is not in your classpath, when you run with java -jar it takes the classpath from the jar&#39;s manifest file, and jpos.jar classpath does not include the current directory. You need to set the classpath externally to include the current directory for instance java -cp .:jpos.jar:<all other jars> org.jpos.q2.Q2

Comment: so do i need to add the whole build folder to the class path at against all the jars inside the lib folder?

Comment: @Dexter I tried to understand what you are saying, but couldn't follow. Yo just need to add all the jars in the lib folder, the jpos jar, and build build directory to the classpath. It's plain basic java, once you have that running, you can focus on how to simplify the launching

Comment: @Dexter, and again you missed the casing, config is all in lower.

Comment: @Dexter "i am executing it by calling java -jar jposee.jar to start q2" how do you run your main then? Why don't you include the META-INF in the jar if you are building it?

Comment: i have edited the config folder and also set org.jpos.q2.Q2 as my Main class and my working directory to the build folder, but yet still the same

Comment: @Dexter. And again, how are you launching your program now? Are you 100% sure, the build folder is in your classpath? Classpath is not the same as working directory, is where java looks for classes and resources. If the working dir is build, but you don't add "." to the classpath then the META-INF directory will not be accessible as a resource.